# Can't run console program in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

i have a little command line named **run.bat**

Which is i want change my IP Address setting with command like this

> run.bat

```
:: netsh interface ipv4
netsh
interface
ip
:: Change ip address
set address "Ethernet" static 192.168.30.77 255.255.255.0 192.168.30.2
```

the command worked as my expected when i type at CMD directly, but not worked when i put it in **run.bat**
and i sure i have run it with administrator access

Comment: only open new CMD with "netsh>" in first line

Answer (score 0):

it works at command line, because you start `netsh` (see how the prompt changes) and then directly interact with the `netsh` program (you should `exit` it finally). It doesn't work in batchfile, because it executes the first command `netsh` - and waits until it's finished (which will happen, when you type `exit`). Then your batchfile tries to execute the next line, but `ip` is not a valid command...

But there is also a "direct mode" for `netsh`: just enter in one line: `netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet" static 192.168.30.77 255.255.255.0 192.168.30.2` (works both in batchfiles and on command line)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
i have put new command :  

`netsh interface ip set address name="lan" static 192.168.30.3 255.255.255.0 192.168.30.2  
netsh interface ip set dnsservers name="lan" static 192.168.30.2  
netsh interface ip add dns name="lan" 8.8.8.8 index=2  
pause  `
  
but i get this message : The configured DNS server is incorrect or does not exist.  

which is make i confused. because i have done of my setting with properly. and successfully ping to **www.google.com**